# .NET Url rewrite the root url

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have the follow rule in IIS7:

```
    <rule name="RewriteAll" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.png$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.gif$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.jpg$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.css$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.js$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?page={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

That catch urls like http://mysite.com/contact/

I can't figure out with rule to use to catch  http://mysite.com/ and send to for example home.aspx. Can anyone help me with the match regex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following rule:

```
 <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup a canonical name (CName) on your DNS server to automatically redirect http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com?

See the [CName explanation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

Comment: Leaving negative feedback without even an explanation comment is pretty poor.

Comment: Agreed that -ves without feedback is poor. Similar suggestion here was also downvoted http://serverfault.com/a/88042