# Redirecting from Root to Index in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't quite figure out how to do this.

I have an ASP.NET site on an IIS server at work for internal usage only and whenever I access the root link foo.dk it shows me an HTTP Error 403 which is fine because that location is not supposed to be accessed.

What instead should happen is that the user is redirected to foo.dk/Index but here is where I have issues. At first I went into the IIS and looked at the HTTP Redirect section. Here I assumed that if I put in foo.dk/Index it would redirect to that page whenever foo.dk was accessed. Instead I get a "Loop at Redirect" error where it tries to redirect forever.

I then went into Default Document and se my Index.aspx page as the default one. This didn't solve the issue either. I tried to use the Web.config file to write a rule that would accomplish what I want but this changed the 403 error to a 500 error on every single page making it completely inaccessible.

I have tried quite a few things now and would like to know if anyone else knows what I could do to achieve what I want:

**Whenever the user access foo.dk I want the IIS to redirect the user to foo.dk/Index**

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And What is index? is it a page(i.e. index.html) or is there an index.aspx, index controller etc....

Comment: starting with the redirect forever part, are you able to browse the page you are intending it to land on? Because it sounds like the permissions are wrong to view it and hence starts the redirect on 403 (permissions) error all over again. I am trying to guess where you are going with redirecting, is it possible you just need URL rewrite rules instead?

Comment: @JackM It is an aspx file yes.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno I tried using a rewrite rule but it changed the error from 403 to 500.

Comment: Did you look in the windows event logs to see if there was anything to tell you what causes the 500 error? Maybe it was just a syntax error.

Comment: I noticed in this article, it also mentions about avoiding redirecting .NET resources. that could have caused the 500 error when the rewrite rule was in place. http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno I'm not sure how I can use what is in the article.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I am over thinking it.. would a rewrite like this example work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550777/net-url-rewrite-the-root-url