# Angular deployment issue on IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I have a localized angular app that I am trying to deploy on IIS.
When I try to load the app, the content of the root folder is served instead of the default index page

Here's what is served:

[image]

When I click on the individual languages, the app loads correctly.

This is how I am building the app:

ng build --base-href / --configuration production

this is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularRoutesEn" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^en/" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./en/index.html" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularRoutesAr" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^ar/" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./ar/index.html" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularRoutesPt" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^pt/" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./pt/index.html" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularRoutesFR" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./fr/index.html" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>        
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Edit #1

Here 's the /fr/index.html @Kostas

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr" dir="ltr"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Meerkat</title>
  <base href="/fr/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-black:#000;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-gray-100:#f8f9fa;--bs-gray-200:#e9ecef;--bs-gray-300:#dee2e6;--bs-gray-400:#ced4da;--bs-gray-500:#adb5bd;--bs-gray-600:#6c757d;--bs-gray-700:#495057;--bs-gray-800:#343a40;--bs-gray-900:#212529;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark:#212529;--bs-primary-rgb:13,110,253;--bs-secondary-rgb:108,117,125;--bs-success-rgb:25,135,84;--bs-info-rgb:13,202,240;--bs-warning-rgb:255,193,7;--bs-danger-rgb:220,53,69;--bs-light-rgb:248,249,250;--bs-dark-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-white-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-black-rgb:0,0,0;--bs-body-color-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-body-bg-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-font-sans-serif:system-ui,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue","Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";--bs-font-monospace:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;--bs-gradient:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));--bs-body-font-family:var(--bs-font-sans-serif);--bs-body-font-size:1rem;--bs-body-font-weight:400;--bs-body-line-height:1.5;--bs-body-color:#212529;--bs-body-bg:#fff;--bs-border-width:1px;--bs-border-style:solid;--bs-border-color:#dee2e6;--bs-border-color-translucent:rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-border-radius:.375rem;--bs-border-radius-sm:.25rem;--bs-border-radius-lg:.5rem;--bs-border-radius-xl:1rem;--bs-border-radius-2xl:2rem;--bs-border-radius-pill:50rem;--bs-link-color:#0d6efd;--bs-link-hover-color:#0a58ca;--bs-code-color:#d63384;--bs-highlight-bg:#fff3cd}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:no-preference){:root{scroll-behavior:smooth}}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-body-font-family);font-size:var(--bs-body-font-size);font-weight:var(--bs-body-font-weight);line-height:var(--bs-body-line-height);color:var(--bs-body-color);text-align:var(--bs-body-text-align);background-color:var(--bs-body-bg);-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}:root{--surface-a:#ffffff;--surface-b:#f8f9fa;--surface-c:#e9ecef;--surface-d:#dee2e6;--surface-e:#ffffff;--surface-f:#ffffff;--text-color:#495057;--text-color-secondary:#6c757d;--primary-color:#2196F3;--primary-color-text:#ffffff;--font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;--surface-0:#ffffff;--surface-50:#FAFAFA;--surface-100:#F5F5F5;--surface-200:#EEEEEE;--surface-300:#E0E0E0;--surface-400:#BDBDBD;--surface-500:#9E9E9E;--surface-600:#757575;--surface-700:#616161;--surface-800:#424242;--surface-900:#212121;--gray-50:#FAFAFA;--gray-100:#F5F5F5;--gray-200:#EEEEEE;--gray-300:#E0E0E0;--gray-400:#BDBDBD;--gray-500:#9E9E9E;--gray-600:#757575;--gray-700:#616161;--gray-800:#424242;--gray-900:#212121;--content-padding:1rem;--inline-spacing:.5rem;--border-radius:3px;--surface-ground:#f8f9fa;--surface-section:#ffffff;--surface-card:#ffffff;--surface-overlay:#ffffff;--surface-border:#dee2e6;--surface-hover:#e9ecef;--maskbg:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);--focus-ring:0 0 0 .2rem #a6d5fa;color-scheme:light}*{box-sizing:border-box}:root{--blue-50:#f4fafe;--blue-100:#cae6fc;--blue-200:#a0d2fa;--blue-300:#75bef8;--blue-400:#4baaf5;--blue-500:#2196f3;--blue-600:#1c80cf;--blue-700:#1769aa;--blue-800:#125386;--blue-900:#0d3c61;--green-50:#f6fbf6;--green-100:#d4ecd5;--green-200:#b2ddb4;--green-300:#90cd93;--green-400:#6ebe71;--green-500:#4caf50;--green-600:#419544;--green-700:#357b38;--green-800:#2a602c;--green-900:#1e4620;--yellow-50:#fffcf5;--yellow-100:#fef0cd;--yellow-200:#fde4a5;--yellow-300:#fdd87d;--yellow-400:#fccc55;--yellow-500:#fbc02d;--yellow-600:#d5a326;--yellow-700:#b08620;--yellow-800:#8a6a19;--yellow-900:#644d12;--cyan-50:#f2fcfd;--cyan-100:#c2eff5;--cyan-200:#91e2ed;--cyan-300:#61d5e4;--cyan-400:#30c9dc;--cyan-500:#00bcd4;--cyan-600:#00a0b4;--cyan-700:#008494;--cyan-800:#006775;--cyan-900:#004b55;--pink-50:#fef4f7;--pink-100:#fac9da;--pink-200:#f69ebc;--pink-300:#f1749e;--pink-400:#ed4981;--pink-500:#e91e63;--pink-600:#c61a54;--pink-700:#a31545;--pink-800:#801136;--pink-900:#5d0c28;--indigo-50:#f5f6fb;--indigo-100:#d1d5ed;--indigo-200:#acb4df;--indigo-300:#8893d1;--indigo-400:#6372c3;--indigo-500:#3f51b5;--indigo-600:#36459a;--indigo-700:#2c397f;--indigo-800:#232d64;--indigo-900:#192048;--teal-50:#f2faf9;--teal-100:#c2e6e2;--teal-200:#91d2cc;--teal-300:#61beb5;--teal-400:#30aa9f;--teal-500:#009688;--teal-600:#008074;--teal-700:#00695f;--teal-800:#00534b;--teal-900:#003c36;--orange-50:#fff8f2;--orange-100:#fde0c2;--orange-200:#fbc791;--orange-300:#f9ae61;--orange-400:#f79530;--orange-500:#f57c00;--orange-600:#d06900;--orange-700:#ac5700;--orange-800:#874400;--orange-900:#623200;--bluegray-50:#f7f9f9;--bluegray-100:#d9e0e3;--bluegray-200:#bbc7cd;--bluegray-300:#9caeb7;--bluegray-400:#7e96a1;--bluegray-500:#607d8b;--bluegray-600:#526a76;--bluegray-700:#435861;--bluegray-800:#35454c;--bluegray-900:#263238;--purple-50:#faf4fb;--purple-100:#e7cbec;--purple-200:#d4a2dd;--purple-300:#c279ce;--purple-400:#af50bf;--purple-500:#9c27b0;--purple-600:#852196;--purple-700:#6d1b7b;--purple-800:#561561;--purple-900:#3e1046;--red-50:#fff5f5;--red-100:#ffd1ce;--red-200:#ffada7;--red-300:#ff8980;--red-400:#ff6459;--red-500:#ff4032;--red-600:#d9362b;--red-700:#b32d23;--red-800:#8c231c;--red-900:#661a14;--primary-50:#f4fafe;--primary-100:#cae6fc;--primary-200:#a0d2fa;--primary-300:#75bef8;--primary-400:#4baaf5;--primary-500:#2196f3;--primary-600:#1c80cf;--primary-700:#1769aa;--primary-800:#125386;--primary-900:#0d3c61}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.d1829a8d245e12b3.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.d1829a8d245e12b3.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.b96b09f300c265bb.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.3bcdb4b6f7fbfdb0.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.8986d35488c9ad03.js" defer></script><script src="main.b16ae2b222b6ec6f.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

I find odd that there's no index file in the root folder itself...

Edit #2

I noticed that if I enter ANYTHING after the base url and press enter, the site loads correctly

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Could you please add the index file?

Comment: Hi @KostasNitaf, I added the index file

Comment: Hi! i think that your problem is in index file `<base href="/fr/">`
May i suggest to change it to `<base href="/">` to see if it works?

Comment: @KostasNitaf this is not related to this as angular will generate this base href for each localized version of application. I think problem is in iis configuration.

Comment: @Amokachi I'm not strong in iis and backend dev but check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550777/net-url-rewrite-the-root-url maybe it helps

Comment: This file is auto-generated @kostas. Every language has a different base ref value

Comment: @Maksat Rahmanov it is very difficult to reproduce the problem in order to help you more :( 
I had a similar problem in IIS deployment and the mistake was on building index href. and It is odd that there's no index file in the root folder !!

Comment: I had experience with configuring nginx to make angular localized application work. Overall idea is to define paths and return necessary index.html files. Example /en -> ./en/index.html. But in nginx config I added this rule / -> ./<defaultLang>/index.html. For root path (/) default language is used. I think @Amokachi is trying to do same thing. In case of root path you should redirect to some language because there is no root index.html as you guys mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by following this:

https://communitysupport.squaredup.com/hc/en-us/articles/4556429603357-How-to-configure-a-redirect-using-the-IIS-URL-Rewrite-module

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the linked article to the answer. Links may change or become dead over time.